# What is the tag [google-calendar-reminders] for?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [google-calendar-reminders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-reminders) is pretty old, with questions dating back to 2013. Presumably, it refers to the fact that entering events in a calendar is a way to be reminded of them.  But the phrase "Google Calendar Reminder" took on a new meaning this year, when Google [added Reminders](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/04/reminders-come-to-google-calendar-on-the-web.html) as a new type of calendar entry, distinct from Events.

Should the tag be used for these new Reminders only, hence be removed from old questions?

Or not, considering there is no counterpart tag [google-calendar-events](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-events)?

Do we even need this tag at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it originally referenced the notifications one could receive from Google Calendar for an event.

I would tend to agree with you that nowadays that tag should be for the new Reminders feature. <del>Those old questions probably need editing.</del> <del>Certainly the tag wiki and excerpt need editing.</del> We *might* need a `google-calendar-notifications` tag (but I'd say probably not).

Comment: Yes, I agree we don't need more google-calendar-* tags. The entire google-calendar tag has 83 questions so far this year, that's one question per 2-3 days.